# Dataframes: Replace Value in Column If 2 Separate Conditions are Met

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Logic I'm trying to implement:

1. If 'phasename' column contains C1, C2, C4, or C18 AND 'reqmnt' column contains C
2. Replace C in requirement column with value in 'phasename' column
3. *Otherwise* leave 'reqmnt' column as is

Below is a sample screen shot of what I'm trying to do
[image]

Currently, I'm not able to figure out how to incorporate the "and" condition into my python code.  So I'm getting the results from current_column in the screen shot.

```
# create mapping dictionary
phasename_dictionary = {'C1':'C1', 'C2':'C2', 'C4':'C4', 'C18':'C18'}
# replace column value
df.loc[df['phasename'].isin(phasename_dictionary.keys()), 'reqmnt'] = \
       df['phasename'].map(phasename_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for `np.where`:

```
v = ['C1', 'C2', 'C4', 'C18']
df.reqmnt = np.where(df.phasename.isin(v) & df.reqmnt.eq('C'), df.phasename, df.reqmnt)
```

Comment: ah! perfect ... this worked great ; thank you so much

Comment: @PineNuts0 For future reference, 1) please post your data and output as text, and 2) you can upvote answers if they helped ;) Same for your previous questions.